# MacPorts python stop tab completion

Tags: python, macos, macports

I have a macport version of python installed. However in the interactive prompt the behavior differs from the normal sane Mac system installed python.

Mac System python interpreter will put a tab when you press tab

MacPorts Python interpreter however will, if you have nothing typed on that line, display all your files in the current path.

How do you get rid of this MacPorts tab completion?

Comment: What version of python and which interpreter? Tab completion is not a normal part of the standard interactive interpreter and would normally need a `.pythonrc` or using a non-standard interpreter, e.g. `ipython`

Comment: It is the normal python interpreter. Python 2.7.11

Comment: I have 2.7 macports version of python and do not get tab completion on blank line (or in fact anywhere). Is the environment variable `PYTHONSTARTUP` set?

Comment: Nope nothing is printed but a new line with echo $PYTHONSTARTUP . However when the macports python is selected and run and a tab pressed at the prompt, the files in the current directory are printed. Switch to apple python 27 and no longer the effect.

Comment: One differences are that apple is python 2.7.10 and mac ports is python 2.7.11 and "Apple LLVM 7.0.0 (clang-700.0.59.5)]" (apple) vs "Apple LLVM 7.0.2 (clang-700.1.81)" (mac ports)

Comment: My MacPorts python is 2.7.11 [GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 7.3.0 (clang-703.0.29)] and I get a tab when I press tab on a new line.

Comment: Cannot reproduce on MacPorts Python 2.7

Comment: Huh I'll have to see if it stays with updated versions